Collation in SQLite for case-sensitive/binary
What is the opposite of COLLATE NOCASE in SQLite? Is there something like COLLATE YESCASE or COLLATE WITHCASE?

COLLATE YESCASE would be equivalent to COLLATE BINARY in SQLite: https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation:

When SQLite compares two strings, it uses a collating sequence or collating function (two terms for the same thing) to determine which string is greater or if the two strings are equal. SQLite has three built-in collating functions: BINARY, NOCASE, and RTRIM.

